# Problem with MS Excel MDS addon - unable to connect to the web app

Tags: excel, master-data-services

I have a new installation of MDS and SQL Server 2016. Installed the Excel plugin too, but unable to connect to the web app. I keep getting this error "there was no endpoint listening at <> that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details (mscorlib)"

The URL is correct, I don't have extra items in the URL (like default.aspx etc). It isn't https, just http. The same URL works in the browser.

What else can I check?

Comment: Can you show what connection string you are using? Perhaps you do not have the correct port designated?

Answer (score 2):

One of the business user in my organization ran into the same issue.  The MDS 2016 URL worked from his laptop browser but the same URL from Excel throwing the same exact error message.  One of my sysadmin suggested that the user run the Excel as administrator.  That solved the issue.  I hope this helps someone reading this link looking for solution.

Comment: Saravanan's solution worked for me. Just to add...also restart Excel if you edit the URL.

Comment: As simple as ... something. I worked for me too. I've tried many sugestions with opening protocols etc., but his one worked. Thank you Saravanan Radhakrishnan :)